# Image won't show on Android 4.0

Tags: android, image, imageview, loading, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a problem. When the app has loaded an image from a web it should show up but on Android 4.0 it doesn't show up. It works on android 2.2.

Here is the code.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imview);
        Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWeb("http://alphaapplication.com/liveshit/free/tour_dates/images/ad.png");
        imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

    public void ad (View view) {
        ad("https://market.android.com/search?q=pub%3A%22Alpha%20Application%22");
    }

    private void ad (String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }

    private Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exc="+e);
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in Honeycomb, 3.X.X, you can no longer access the network from your main UI thread.  Which is what you're doing in the code snippet you just provided.  Now, you need to move all network accesses to a background thread.  The easiest way to accomplish this is by using AsyncTask.  I've linked you to the developer guide that should make it pretty easy for you to transition your code.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Just to validate, you should look in logcat, and your app would probably have quietly thrown a  NetworkOnMainThreadException, but it's not enough to cause your app to blow up because it's informational; not a system halt.

Let me know if that works for you, or else look for the exception being thrown in logcat and reply here

DSC

Comment: what was the exception you got? As promethium said after honeycomb you need to use asynctask or handler if you will make network operation.

Answer (score 1):

pr0methium is right.
http://developer.aiwgame.com/imageview-show-image-from-url-on-android-4-0.html

.......
// show The Image
        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
                .execute("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");
    }

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, IndexActivity.class));
    finish();

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```